# Почему я не могу использовать member: discord.Member в нескольких командах?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Я новичок в питоне, делаю бота
Как я могу сделать несколько параметров  member: discord.Member в нескольких командах?
При использовании команды которая выше всех стоит в коде все нормально, а потом ошибка discord.ext.commands.errors.missingrequiredargument: member is a required argument that is missing.

Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему

Comment: Опишите проблему более подробно, добавьте код, описывающий то, как вы пытались решить эту проблему самостоятельно.

Comment: @towerty я думаю, что мой код нарушает правила, т.к. содержит нецензурную лексику. Но, я пытался исправить ошибку
 `if member is not None:
    await ctx.send("{} сделал убил {}. {} теперь мертв (official).".format(ctx.message.author.mention, member.mention,member.mention))` 
и так с каждой командой где использовалось member

Comment: Можете ли вы добавить код непосредственно в сам вопрос? Читать его из комментариев трудно. И ещё - не храните в коде бота нецензурную лексику, дабы не задеть пользователей.